# Handle webGL particles independently

Tags: javascript, attributes, webgl, particles, particle-system

I created this particle system with scratch webGL code and i would translate the particles emitter you can experiment here :
https://codepen.io/stephanemill/pen/vYWgKNP

By moving particles, I want to **new particles run in new direction, but previous stay in their initial direction.**

...Like on this render (movment is due to the mouse in this case) : https://ics-creative.github.io/ParticleJS/docs/examples/mouse-tracking.html

Here is my vertex shader code :

```
            void main(void) {
                gl_PointSize = size;                    
                vColor = color; 
            
                // Settings of the particle
                // ---------------------------------
                float modTime   = time / timeFactor;                    
                float speed     = speed_angle_offset.x;
                float angle     = speed_angle_offset.y;
                float offset    = speed_angle_offset.z;                 
                float G         = gravity.x;                    
                float x0        = position.x;
                float y0        = position.y;
                                    
                // Calculations for the non-ending particle flow
                // -------------------------------------------------
                float offsetStart   = abs(offset) * lifetime;
                float offsetTime    = clamp(modTime - offsetStart, 0., 2e10);
                offsetTime          = mod(offsetTime, lifetime);
                
                // Moving emitter... The problem IS HERE
                // -------------------------------------------------
                if(modTime - offsetTime > deltaXYT.z ){
                    x0  = x0 + deltaXYT.x;
                    y0  = y0 + deltaXYT.y;
                }

                // Equations of parabolic shoot to set x and y position 
                // -----------------------------------------------------
                float x = speed * cos(angle) * offsetTime + x0;
                float y = -.5 * G * pow(offsetTime, 2.) + speed * sin(angle) * offsetTime + y0;
                
                
                // Ratio canvas
                // ---------------------------------
                x /= ratio;
                
                                    
                // Printing particle
                // ---------------------------------
                gl_Position=vec4(x, y, 0, 1.);    
            }`;
```

*About my code :*

- The translation on the Y axis is creating **line 50** with a setinterval for a slow visualization.
- My solution is to create a deltaXYT uniform (**line 380**) which embedded the X delta, the Y delta, and the exact time (this.time) the delta position is applied to the X,Y position of each particle.
- This technique is implemented in the getVertexShader function **line 430** (Moving emitter)

As you can see, the result is not that i expect, because each particle doesn't memorize its own deltaXY in order to run its own way... So what you're seeing is a batch of young particles running on the most recent deltaXYT, and a batch of other particles running on the default deltaXYT **line 155** (which brings no modification on position attribute)

I suppose i'm not in the right way, so did you have any suggestion to do this thing, which, at the beginning, didn't seem so hard.

Comment: It seems that the solution is to use the transformFeedback feature.

Answer (score 0):

Each particle should have a birth time, but also a birth position.
This position will change at every particle reborn and cannot be computed by the vertex shader. Especially if it is a mouse position, for example.
You need to store this new position somewhere.

One solution could be to store it in the attributes:

- attribute vec2 attInitialPosition;
- attribute vec2 attInitialSpeed;
- attribute float attBirthTime;

Then the "reborn" logic can be delegated to Javascript code that will update the attributes once changed.

Of course, sending the whole Data Array for all the 500 particles is not a good idea.
Instead, we can just send what has changed.

To explain the trick in an easy way, let's assume we will create a new particle at each frame. That means that we will create particles at a rate of 60 per seconds if we are lucky.

Then, at first frame, you update the attributes of vertex 1, at frame 2 the attributes of vertex 2, etc...
Of course at frame 501 you update again the attributes of vertex 1 and so on.

With 500 particules, that means that each one will leave for 500 * 16 ms = 8 seconds.

And at each frame, you can update the vertex like this:

```
    public pushDataSubArray(data: Float32Array, start: number, end: number) {
        const { gl, vertBuff } = this
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuff)
        const subData = data.subarray(start * 5, end * 5)
        gl.bufferSubData(
            gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 
            start * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT * 5,
            subData
        )
    }
```

The `subarray()` method is super cool because it does not copy de data.
It's more like a window on a portion of your initial array.

---

Of course if you need more control, you will decide how many particles you update per frame depending on the rate and the lifetime you want. But I won't give you an example here because it complexifies the code and make it more difficult to understand.

Here is the vertex shader code:

```
uniform float uniTime;

attribute vec2 attInitialPosition;
attribute vec2 attInitialSpeed;
attribute float attBirthTime;

varying vec3 varColor;

const vec2 GRAVITY = vec2(0, -1) * 0.0000005;
const vec3 YELLOW = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 0.1);
const vec3 RED = vec3(0.8, 0.0, 0.0);

void main() {
    float t = uniTime - attBirthTime;
    float t2 = t * t;
    gl_Position = vec4(
        t2 * GRAVITY + t * attInitialSpeed + attInitialPosition,
        0.5, 1.0
    );
    gl_PointSize = 128.0 - 0.02 * t;
    float life = clamp(t * 0.005, 0.0, 1.0);
    float light = 11.0 - 10.0 * life * life;
    varColor = light * mix(YELLOW, RED, life);
}
```

See it in action here (move your mouse on the screen to change the birth location):

https://codepen.io/tolokoban/pen/zYPZJJX?editors=0010

Comment: Thank you for this solution. If I well understand, gl.bufferSubData will replace initial positions of each particle by their new one at the right place in the buffer Data? This avoids  to replace all the buffer with a gl.bufferData() ?
Isn't it too costly for the GPU?

Comment: It would be costly if you updated the whole buffer, but here we are talking about few bytes, so that's totally fine.

Comment: Hi (after a very long time, sorry !)
I don't understand a part of this code : for me, it seems you don't change anything in subData before putting it in the buffer... so how does it work ?

const subData = data.subarray(start * 5, end * 5)
gl.bufferSubData(
            gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 
            start * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT * 5,
            subData
        )

Comment: `data` is an array in Javascript memory and with `bufferSubData` we push only a part of it to the GPU memory. And I use `pokeData` to update a part of `data` in Javascript memory (at line 310 in CodePen).

Comment: It seems that subarray is updating the buffer at the correct position without needing bufferSubData.
I will post my solution, inspired by yours but using some different small details. I had an other constraint that i didn't mentionned : i need multiple emitters at the same time, with different trajectories.

Comment: The `subarray` I used on line 198 works on an array that is in CPU memory. But then you have to push it in GPU memory. How do you do that without `gl.bufferSubData`? I'm interested in your solution.

Comment: Here is my solution : https://millgraphik.fr/webgl/webgl_9-object.html
  and here is the code : http://millgraphik.fr/webgl/js/webgl_9.js

The interesting point is the updatePosition() function where I'm rebinding all the buffer after the subarray edit. I must rebind all the buffer because there is multiple emitter working at the same time. But maybe you'll have a better way ??

Comment: Note that i have to rebind at each frame update all the attributes buffers (this one for the time, this one for the angle and speed, and this one for the position)
I'm not convinced but this is the only way I found.

Comment: I see that in your `loop()` function you call several `update*()` function which, in turn, use `gl.bufferData()`. So you are sending the whole buffers to the GPU at each loop, don't you?

Comment: Yes. There is a lot of loop turning at the same time, but one GL environment. So, for each particles emitter object, I have to push the correct buffers to the GPU (but the content of the buffer isn't modified, except for the position buffer, which is the subarray part)

Comment: Note that it's the only solution i found to make work several emitter at the same time. If you have a better solution, I take it !